# Why do I get error using Ant to create mysql database?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ant, installation

**Machine and Background:** OSX 10.5.8 32-bit. MySQL password is "" i.e. empty

**Goal:** I'm trying to use the Java Database Connector (JDBC) tutorials. I'm currently at [this step](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html#step10).

**Error:** With the shell at the directory where I have the JDBC Tutorial, I enter `sudo ant create-mysql-database` and get the following error:

> Buildfile: /Users/adam/Desktop/JDBCTutorial/build.xml
>
> create-mysql-database:
>
> BUILD FAILED /Users/adam/Desktop/JDBCTutorial/build.xml:73:
> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES)     at
> com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)     at
> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
> at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
> at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
> at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:813)    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)    at
> com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.JDBCTask.getConnection(JDBCTask.java:370)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.getConnection(SQLExec.java:942)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:614)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

**Self-Rectification Efforts:** I tried adding `grant all on initdb.* to 'root'@'127.0.0.1' identified by ''`to the end of the command per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031419/ant-couldnt-connect-to-mysql-access-denied-but-mysql-client-could). Same error. It seems to be denying access to ant to do stuff; maybe if I turned off the using password option to NO, it would work; I tried googling around for that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

In the JDBC tutorial folder's *build.xml* file, search for the string "create-mysql-database"; the string labels a task defined in the *.xml* file. Identify the value for the "password" parameter in that block of text (easier when reading the text with highlighting programs such as *Dashcode*), and change it to something that works with the system's databases (in my case "").

Having found what the string was in "password" before editing, find that same string throughout the *.xml* file and replace it with the correct password

Lesson: Apparently *ant* takes the string you passed in when invoking it (i.e. the string after the string "ant"), and looks for it in the *build.xml* present in the directory at which you invoked the program. Don't have the wrong password...

Answer (score 0):

Me too got struck at same place with same error in JDBC tutorials, as per **whearyou** suggestion, I just added my original password "YES" (which I created while making MySQL setup) in properties/mysql-build-properties.xml at line no: 28   .

Then it worked...!